# How to go to one or another page according to the chosen option

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am in the development of a form and I want to know how I can go to one or another page, according to the option chosen in a radio button, so far I have the following form with two radio buttons:

```css
.sh_k .sh_sl {
    background-color: #edf7f8;
    color: #282828;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sh_k .sh_sn {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sh_k .sh_st {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 60%;
}

.sh_k .sh_sz {
    width: 100%;
}

.sh_u9 {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.sh_cq {
    font-size: 16px!important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bpv_cq {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Lettera Text Std;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h5.bpv_cq {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.sh_vm {
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.bpv_cq.bpv_bpx {
    color: #282828;
}

.sh_qj:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.sh_qj {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sh_vb {
    width: 50%!important;
}

.sh_un {
    margin-top: 20px!important;
    width: 31%;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq {
    border: 2px solid #0c3970;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: border-color .2s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
}

.b3n_ag9 label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b3n_ag9 span {
    color: #3b3f3b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.b3n_ag9 input {
    appearance: none;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq.b3n_lk:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq:before {
    background-color: #63666A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #63666A;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: opacity .2s ease,transform .2s ease;
    width: 12px;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq.b3n_lk, .b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq:hover {
    border-color: #63666A;
}

.b3n_ag9 input:checked:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
  top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="content">
 <div class="box">
<div class="box-body">
<form class="sh_k" id="form">
              <div class="sh_sn">
                  <div class="sh_u9">
                      <h5 class="sh_cq bpv_cq bpv_bpx">
                        <span class="bpv_bpz">
                            Select a option
                        </span>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sh_qj sh_vm sh_vb">
                      <div class="sh_un b3n_ag9">
                        <label for="dnaelaboracion">
                            <div id="elaboracion-radio" class="b3n_lq">                                    
                               <input name="dna" id="dnaelaboracion" type="radio" value="elaboracion"> 
                            </div>
                            <span>Elaboration</span>                                      
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="sh_un b3n_ag9">
                        <label for="dnarevision">
                            <div id="revision-radio" class="b3n_lq">
                                <input name="dna" id="dnarevision" type="radio" value="revision"> 
                            </div>
                            <span>Revision</span>
                      </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="sh_p0 sh_wl">
                  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="lu_g5 lu_l2">Next</button>
              </div>         
          </form>
              </div>  
                 </div>  

 </section>
  </div>  
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

If I select Elaboration, it will go to `elaboration.html`, if I select Revision it will go to `revision.html` after pressing the next button.

I hope someone can give me an orientation to complete this form.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is by storing the URI in the radio button `value` attribute and then retrieving it with an event listener.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form id="form">
    <div>
        <label for="dnaelaboracion">
            <div id="elaboracion-radio">
                <input name="dna" id="dnaelaboracion" type="radio" value="page1.html">
            </div>
            <span>Elaboration</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="dnarevision">
            <div id="revision-radio">
                <input name="dna" id="dnarevision" type="radio" value="page2.html">
            </div>
            <span>Revision</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

<!-- JS -->
<script>
    const button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = document.querySelector('input[name="dna"]:checked').value;
});
</script>
```

If you don't like using the `value` attribute for this purpose, you could also store it in a [data attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: It seems that your answer works, in the case that I want to redirect to a specific route in my project, can I add it in the `value`?

Comment: Yes. It will treat anything in the value attribute as a URI. You can use relative or absolute paths, but it will force a full reload of the page.